GRPC issue with NestJS
I try to call an grpc python service with NestJS client I pass my parameter on the call and the python API return to me an error "Invalid URL: The 'pdf_url' field is empty".
When I try to do the call with my terminal the parameter is correctly receive by my python API.
So I don't know where my NestJS conf is not good.
pdf.proto (NestJS & Python service)
syntax = "proto3";

package pdfwhitespace;

service PDFWhitespaceService {
  rpc FindWhitestSpace (PDFRequest) returns (WhitespaceResponse) {}
}

message PDFRequest {
  string pdf_url = 1;
}

message WhitespaceResponse {
  message PageWhitespace {
    int32 page_number = 1;
    float left = 2;
    float top = 3;
    float width = 4;
    float height = 5;
  }
  repeated PageWhitespace whitespaces = 1;
}

server.py
class PDFWhitespaceServicer(pdf_whitespace_pb2_grpc.PDFWhitespaceServiceServicer):
def FindWhitestSpace(self, request, context):
        print(f"Raw request received: {request}")
        if not request.pdf_url:
            print("Field 'pdf_url' is missing or empty")
            context.set_details("Invalid URL: The 'pdf_url' field is empty")
            context.set_code(grpc.StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT)
            return pdf_whitespace_pb2.WhitespaceResponse()
        print(f"Received URL: {request.pdf_url}")

NestJS config :
app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      cache: true,
      load: [
        ...
        PdfWhitespaceMicroserviceConfig,
      ],
    }),
    ...
  ],
  controllers: [...],
  providers: [...],
})

microservice.config.js
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { join } from 'path';

export default registerAs('pdf-whitespace-microservice', () => ({
  transport: Transport.GRPC,
  options: {
    url: 'pdf-whitespace-microservice:50051',
    package: 'pdfwhitespace', // Doit correspondre au package défini dans .proto
    protoPath: join(__dirname, '../../protos/pdf_whitespace.proto'), // Chemin correct
  },
}));

pdf.service.ts
interface PageWhitespace {
  page_number: number;
  left: number;
  top: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface WhitespaceResponse {
  whitespaces: PageWhitespace[];
}

interface GRPCPdfService {
  FindWhitestSpace(data: string): Observable<WhitespaceResponse>;
}

@Injectable()
export class PdfService extends ALoggerService {
  private grpcService: GRPCPdfService;

  constructor(@Inject('PDF_WHITESPACE_PACKAGE') private client: ClientGrpc) {
    super();
    try {
      this.grpcService = this.client.getService<GRPCPdfService>(
        'PDFWhitespaceService',
      );
      this.logger.debug('PDF service connection initialized successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error('Failed to initialize PDF service', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

 async findWhitestSpace(pdf_url: string): Promise<PageWhitespace[]> {
    if (!pdf_url) {
      throw new Error('pdf_url cannot be empty');
    }
    console.log(`'{'pdf_url': '${pdf_url}'}'`);

    // const req = this.grpcService.FindWhitestSpace();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.grpcService.FindWhitestSpace(`{pdf_url:plop}`).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log('Response received:', response);
          resolve(response.whitespaces);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error('gRPC error:', error);
          reject(error);
        },
      );
    });
  }
}

On my terminal I try with this command line :
grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"pdf_url": "https://example.com"}' localhost:50051 pdfwhitespace.PDFWhitespaceService/FindWhitestSpace

And it's return "Received URL: https://example.com"
What's wrong with my NestJS config ?

The issue might lie in how you're handling the pdf_url you are sending.
In your terminal, you are correctly passing an object to the method, like this:
grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"pdf_url": "https://example.com"}' localhost:50051 pdfwhitespace.PDFWhitespaceService/FindWhitestSpace
However in your NestJS method, you're passing a string that doesn't properly map to the expected gRPC object format : {pdf_url:plop}
so your method receiving an undefined property which doesn't match to expected format try pass an object to your method and see if its work correctly
